# iPhone - Objective C, on app launch image

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I'm using the Utility Application template to build my app.
Having a hard time getting an image to show up as the app launch. (I'm having this difficulty with all the templates basically)

Basically, right now when the app launch, it starts with a black background and it takes a second or 2 before the content appears.
However, I see that some apps has an image as it opens up. How do they do that?

I tried adding it to the "UIWindow" and have it set to "visible at launch". It doesn't quite work as expected. (i.e I think it goes behind the views since it is visible only when the views are flipping)

Thank you,
Tee

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `Default.png` image to your resources directory. That should do the trick.

Comment: Oh man, so it needs to have that naming convention. Been tinkering in the XIB file I thought I'm adding it wrong.
Thanks,
Tee